# How to insert an array of integers into a byte array in postgres

Tags: postgresql

how can I insert an array of integers [28452, 28453, 28454, 28468] into a bytea column of postgres?

It would be something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (id, content, my_list) VALUES (1, 'CONTENT', [28452, 28453, 28454, 28468])
```

There is some function that does this conversion directly in the INSERT.

Thank you.

Comment: Why not store it as an array of integers?

Comment: Because the data I have is in an array of integers and the table I want to persist in is already in that bytea type.

Comment: How do you want it stored? If you don't care, just cast to `text` first and then to `bytea`.

Comment: Can you explain how to convert? Because I would need to do this directly in a SQL because I have a lot of data to convert.